# wifi authentication required

Tags: wireless, 22.04, authentication

On my dual boot system, Windows10+Ubuntu 22.04, wifi works in Windows, but not in Ubuntu. It keeps telling "authentication required", even though I entered the right Wireless Key.
I have a Realtek RTL8111 PCI Express network card. I recently got a new modem ZYXEL, because we changed from DSL to optical fiber.
Under tab Security, I tried both WPA 3 personal and WPA 2 personal. I also tried Forget Network and Connect to Hidden Network, but without success. Copy/paste Wireless Key from editor did not work either. Anyone who can help?
sudo rm did not work. Wi-Fi settings say: signal strength Good, security WPA 3. I tried both WPA 3 and WPA 2 but I still get the message "Authentication Required"

Comment: If I were you, I would change the wireless password to a simpler one (only English letters a-z and numerals 0-9) and try.

Comment: Realtek RTL8111 PCI Express is ethernet, not wifi.

Comment: The wireless password is not the problem, because it works on Windows and my smartphone and tablet.

Comment: Ok, the information about Realtek was not relevant. But wireless does work with Windows on the same computer with dual boot system. So Why can I not work with Ubuntu using wifi?

Comment: sudo rm did not work. Wi-Fi settings say: signal strength Good, security WPA 3. I tried both WPA 3 and WPA 2 but I still get the message "Authentication Required"

Comment: Does your wireless device do WPA3? `iw list | grep SAE` Can you set the router to WPA2/WPA3 mixed mode?

Comment: terminal: iw command not found, with or without sudo

Comment: Can you install it by ethernet, tethering, etc.? `sudo apt update && sudo apt install iw` Reboot and tell us if the connectivity has improved.

Comment: @chili555 I used my smartphone as a hotspot. Ubuntu says "connected", but I cannot access the internet with Firefox. In the terminal I tried update and install iw, but I get the message "unable to fetch some archives". Windows works fine with the hotspot.

Comment: @chili555: I have set the router on WPA3-SAE/WPA2-PSK, but I still get "authentication required". Does Ubuntu support WPA2-PSK?

Comment: With your phone as a hotspot, can you: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` May we see: `nmcli dev show | grep DNS
`

Comment: @chili555:  (phone as hotspot) ping -c3 response: Destination Net Unreached. 3 transmitted, 0 received, 3 errors. 100% packet loss. Connection details: signal strength: excellent. Security WPA2. The nmcli command gives nothing in return.

Answer (score 1):

> I recently got a new modem

I suspect that the stored connections have a reference to the old router, most likely an uuid. I suggest that you remove them and try to establish new connections. From the terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

Reboot and try again.